# How to show a text field based on user's selection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom-events

I have an array

```
ABC = ["A","B","C"]

<%= f.select :abc, model::ABC, :include_blank => true %>
```

If I select C, then I want to display an input field for "city" and "state".  Otherwise, those fields should be hidden.  Is there any simple way of doing this. I don't want to use jQuery or  Ajax.

Comment: you mean you want to change which elements are displayed based on the user's selection?

Comment: <%= f.select :abc, model::ABC, :include_blank => true %> This is default case only when I select C I want attribute city and state should show up else <%= f.label :abc %><br />
      <%= f.select :abc, MODEL::ABC, :include_blank => true %> is fine

Comment: do you want the city and state fields to be on the same page as the select menu?  or on the next page?

Comment: same page. I want exact feature like when we fill any kind a form where if we choose "other" options we see a text box to fill.

Comment: is the problem that you don't know jQuery, or that you want your page to work without javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to change what fields are being displayed without using javascript.

What you could do is always display the city and state fields, but only require them if the select menu is set to C. For example, define a validation rule that requires a field if the select menu is set to C.  In your lib/ directory, make `require_if_c_validator.rb`

```
class RequireIfCValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each object, attribute, value
    if object.your_attribute_name == 'C' && value == nil
      object.errors[attribute] < 'is required'
    end
  end
end
```

And then in your model, call it on city and state:

```
validate :city, :require_if_c => true
validate :state, :require_if_c => true
```